# Проверка столкновений

Tags: c++, c++builder

Есть у меня 2 картинки(TImage). Одна не двигается, а вторая передвигается к первой(только по оси Х)
Делал что-то, вроде такого: `return (b->Left <= (a->Left + Width));`
Но это работает не так, как нужно
Как сделать проверку столкновений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все правильно ты думаешь, нужно следить за тем что - координата Х второй картинки не была равной или меньше (координате Х + ширина первой картинки), то есть в коде скорее всего ошибка у тебя.

```
bool check(float xFirstImg, float xSecondImg, float widthFirstImg){
if(xSecondImg <= (xFirstImg + widthFirstImg)){
return true;
return false;
}
```